# accessing structures from a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hi i need help regarding how can i assign g to a specific seat in "assign_guest_at" so i can check it for further conditions (the question is mentioned below).

The function attempts to assign the "g" to the seat at
"row" and "col" (specified by the parameters of this
function). If the seat has a default guest, i.e., a guest
with the last name "???" and the first name "???", then
we can assign the new guest "g" to that seat and the
method returns true. Otherwise, this seat is considered to
be taken by someone else, the method does not assign
the guest and return 0 (false).

```
 struct guest {
        char last_name[30];
        char first_name[30];
    };
    struct auditorium_seating {
        struct guest **seating;
    };
    void guest_init(struct guest *g, char *info) 
    {
        char *token;
        token = strtok(info, "/");
        strcpy(g->first_name, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\0");
        strcpy(g->last_name, token);

    }
    int assign_guest_at(int row, int col, struct auditorium_seating *a, struct guest* g)
    {

        if (a->seating[row][col] == "???")
        {


            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: C does not support _methods_. And there is no method in your snippet.

Comment: sorry it was suppose to be from pointers

Comment: If you don't undestand a comment, doing some research about what it states might help. I did not even mention pointers. Just ot make clear: Ther is no **method** in your snippet. Only a function.

Comment: One more hint: what do you expect `"\0"` to do as an argument to ´strtok`?

Comment: probably to give the last word after "/"

Comment: You can't compare strings like this: `a->seating[row][col] == "???"`

Comment: "probably"?? Did you pick that snippet from some obscure internet post? If it is your's, you should know already what you intend. How about reading the fine (isn't "be nice" just being nice?) manuals?

Comment: What is that "???". Is it a character array or you mean a null pointer ?

Comment: ??? is a char array

Comment: yeah i know about this (a->seating[row][col] == "???") but i have no idea how can i access seating from that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare strings in C there is a function in  named **strcmp**, it compares two strings and return 0 if they're equal.

To use it in your struct you should do it with each field, using your default guest logic.

I think this code below does what you want:

```
int assign_guest_at(int row, int col, struct auditorium_seating *a, struct guest* g)
{

    if ( strcmp(a->seating[row][col].first_name, "???") == 0 && 
            strcmp(a->seating[row][col].last_name, "???") == 0)
    {
        a->seating[row][col] = *g;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by that "???". But if we understand that it is a character array (Perhaps Assigned at initialization) then the following code snippet implements your function:

```
int assign_guest_at(int row, int col, struct auditorium_seating *a, struct guest* g)
{
    if (!strcmp(a->seating[row][col].last_name, "???")  
        && !strcmp(a->seating[row][col].first_name, "???"))
        {
        memcpy(&a->seating[row][col], g, sizeof (struct guest));
        return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

The function checks if the seat at [row][col] have a default guest (As you defined it above with "???" string appended to both last_name & first_name), if it is the case, the seat  `*g` is copied into it.